# export 'registerFirestore' (imported as 'registerFirestore') was not found in '@firebase/firestore

Tags: angular, typescript

i upgrade from angular 10 to 12 ,after update i got this error
i used the official upgrade guide of angular but i didn't find anything related to this issue

```
./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-firestore.js:742:16-33 - Error: 
export 'registerFirestore' (imported as 'registerFirestore') was not found in 
'@firebase/firestore' (possible exports: __PRIVATE_r
egisterFirestore, __esModule)
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths":{
      "crypto":["node_modules/crypto-js"]
    },
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom", "es2017"],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.e2e-spec.ts"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.e2e-spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I install     `"@angular/fire": "6.1.5",`
and solved